# Как получить двоичную последовательность случайных чисел?

Tags: математика, случайные-числа

Если взять остаток от деления каждого члена псевдослучайной последовательности на 2(начальная последовательность чисел может получаться с помощью линейного конгруэнтного метода) ,можно ли считать эту последовательность из 0 и 1 псевдослучайной двоичной последовательностью ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, в общем случае нельзя, потому что линейный конгруэнтный метод периодичен и в ряде случаев может оказаться так, что после взятия остатка от деления на `2` вы получите также линейную конгруэнтную последовательность, а у неё есть важнейшее свойство: период последовательности **не может быть** больше `m` (модуля). Стало быть, при `m=2` вы получаете просто чередующиеся числа `0, 1, 0, 1` и т. д.

Более подробно о псевдослучайных двоичных последовательностях есть в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: Но как тогда получить двоичную последовательность с помощью линейного конгруэнтного метода? И в вопросе шла речь о том,чтобы уже готовые члены последовательности (когда уже ЛКМ отработал) делить с остатком на 2,это не сработает(понимаю,что если в саму формулу брать модуль по m=2,то последовательность зациклится )?

Comment: Я вам ответил, что В ОБЩЕМ СЛУЧАЕ, это НЕ сработает, потому что после **повторного** взятия по модулю может получиться также конгруэнтная последовательность. А может не получиться. Если вы хотели знать как сделать чтобы получилась, то нужно было так и задавать вопрос. Потому что это принципиально другой вопрос, гораздо более сложный.

Comment: Я вас понял ,спасибо большое за ответ